# Como dar echo em uma variável desta função?

Tags: php

Digamos que eu queira dar ***echo*** em ***$path*** fora da função. Como eu posso fazer isso? Parece simples mas eu não sei!

```
function armazena_constantes (){

    $path               = '/home/axitech/www/dent';
    $path_admin         = '/home/axitech/www/dent/admin/';
    $base_url           = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    $base_url_admin     = $base_url . '/admin/';

}
```

Comment: Parece que não está claro pra você o conceito de função: elas devem **fazer algo**, e geralmente **retornam algo**. Essa sua função não faz nenhuma das duas coisas! As variáveis que você cria lá dentro só existem lá dentro mesmo.

Comment: Precisa editar a pergunta novamente, agora não existe nenhuma variável chamada `path` ficou mais estranho ainda O.o

Comment: @bfavaretto tem alguma função no stack pra voltar a pergunta a forma inicial?

Comment: Click no link "editada XX min atrás" vai abrir o histórico de edições, vai na edição que deseja voltar e click em "reverter".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Retorne `$path` no final da sua função. Variáveis locais(aquelas declaradas dentro da função) não são acessiveis em outras partes do código.

Pode definir um array associativo com os diretorios, e pagar a parte desejada informando um argumento na função

```
function base_url($selecionado){
    $dir = ['imagem' => '/imagem/', 'js' => '/js/', 'css' => '/css/'];
    return $dir[$selecionado];
}

//chamada:

echo base_url('css');
```

Outra opção é criar um arquivo com constantes dos diretórios mais importantes e importa ele nos demais arquivos.

cofing.php

```
<?php
define('ROOT_DIR', dirname(__FILE__));
define('FUNCTIONS_DIR', ROOT_DIR .DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. 'functions');
define('IMG_DIR', ROOT_DIR .DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. 'www' .DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. 'img');
define('CSS_DIR', ROOT_DIR .DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. 'www' .DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. 'css');
```

Na demais páginas, faça um include/require para `config.php`, fique atentento para definir o `ROOT_DIR` nesse exemplo parti do ponto que ele está na raiz do projeto.

index.php

```
<?php
include_once 'config.php';
echo 'Raiz do projeto: '. ROOT_DIR . '<br> imagens: '. IMG_DIR;
<img src="<?php echo IMG_DIR.'/logo.jpg'" />
```

Answer (score 5):

Você pode transformar a forma como armazena as variaveis.

```
function armazena_constantes (){
   $array = [];
   $array['path']               = '/home/axitech/www/dent';
   $array['path_admin']         = '/home/axitech/www/dent/admin/';
   $array['base_url']           = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
   $array['base_url_admin']     = $base_url . '/admin/';
   return $array;
}
```

Para acessar basta utilizar:

```
$constantes = armazena_constantes();
echo $contantes['path_admin'];
```

Ou você poderá utilizar por class e definir os valores em objeto, dando `getPathAdmin` e etc para recuperar os valores.

```
class constantes {
   private $path;
   //..

   public function __construct(){

         $this->path = '/home/axitech/www/dent';
        // ...

   }

   public function getPath(){

        return $this->path;

    }
}


$constantes = new Constantes();

echo $constantes->getPath();
```

https://ideone.com/Zf14bX