# É possível incluir mais de um arquivo.php na rota de um Require?

Tags: php, require

Não soube qual era a melhor forma de fazer essa pergunta, mas me deparei com a seguinte dúvida...

Dentro de um documento, possuo alguns require_once (que fui montando durante um tempo), no código eles estão dessa maneira:

```
<?php
   require_once("diretorio/arquivo.php");
   require_once("diretorio/arquivo2.php");
   require_once("diretorio/arquivo3.php");
?>
```

É possível que ao invés de replicar um require_once, eu faça da maneira como vou deixar abaixo?

```
<?php
   require_once("diretorio/arquivo.php", "diretorio/arquivo2.php", "diretorio/arquivo3.php");
?>
```

Mesmo sendo ou não sendo possível, qual seria a melhor maneira de estruturar todos esses require? Um por linha ou tudo em um?

Comment: Sugestão minha, faça um arquivo inc.php onde você adiciona todos os require's, informando o endereço relativo completo. Dai, sempre que precisar fazer um require para alguns arquivos, basta setar para o `inc.php`.

Comment: Porque não importa de um arquivo que contenha todos os arquivos?

Comment: Boa ideia, essa dúvida me surgiu porque tudo se apresenta dentro de um documento (no topo) e as vezes me incomoda ficar vendo umas 3 linhas ocupadas com 20 caracteres. Estou tentando me adaptar as melhores regras de code atualmente.

Comment: Pois é, já que está no topo de outro basta importa-lo ;)

Comment: [Como definir o path para acessar arquivos no sistema procedural](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90217/91)
ou
[Como dar echo em uma variável desta função?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/96734/91)

Comment: De qualquer forma, não posso colocar várias rotas dentro de um require, certo?

Comment: O que você chama de rota? é possível trocar aquela string por uma variável ou constante sim!

Comment: O que eu quero dizer é se existe alguma maneira de evitar replicar o "require_once" e definir somente um com todos os paths. Ou qual seria a maneira correta de fazer isso, enfim, foi só uma dúvida aleatória mesmo.

Comment: Entendi, se os principais arquivos estiverem na mesma pasta, vc pode listar todos esses arquivos e usar um `foreach` para montar o `require`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Digamos que todos os seus arquivos de includes estejam em uma pasta a parte chamada includes e o seu index na raiz do projeto, pode criar uma função que faça todos esses requires/includes.

Use `glob()` para listar todos os arquivos php de includes e faça um foreach.

Estrutura do projeto:

```
Root 
   includes
   public
      html
      css
      js
index
```

Essa função deve estar no seu index ou config.

```
<?php

function includes(){
    foreach(glob('includes/*.php') as $arquivo){
        require_once $arquivo;
    }
}

includes();
```

Faça um teste rápido crie 2 ou 3 arquivos na pasta includes com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
<?php
echo __FILE__ .'<br>';
```

Depois chame o seu index e veja o resultado, algo como:

```
projeto\includes\1.php
projeto\includes\2.php
projeto\includes\3.php
```

Pode também criar um arquivo com constantes dos principais diretórios e passar uma delas no lugar daquela pasta que está fixa em `glob()`.

Answer (score 4):

Ao invés de usar includes manuais, porque você não usa um autoload para todas as classes requeridas?

```
define('PS', PATH_SEPARATOR);
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PS . 'diretorio' . DS);
spl_autoload_extensions('.php, .inc');
spl_autoload_register();
```

Dá pra fazer isso para limitar os arquivos "suaclasse.class.php":

```
define('PS', PATH_SEPARATOR);
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('CLASS_DIR', 'class' . DS);
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PS . CLASS_DIR);

// se quiser atribuir um "class" aos arquivos `/class/file.class.php`
spl_autoload_extensions('.class.php');

spl_autoload_register();
```

De fato, como observou @WallaceMaxters, o correto é usar: **PATH_SEPARATOR**

Existe uma outra forma interessante de fazer que é através do uso do [composer.phar](https://getcomposer.org/download/):

mantendo o arquivo: composer.json

```
{
    "name": "empresa/seuapp",
    "description": "Nome do APP",
    "require": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^4",
        "php": ">=5.3.3"
    },
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "seunome",
            "email": "seuemail@empresa.com.br"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "alpha",
    "config": {
        "vendor-dir": "vendor/"
    }, 
    "autoload": {  
        "psr-4": {
            "SeuApp\\": ["src/"]
        }
    },
    "comments": [
                 "- Para habilitar o autoload, use o comando: php composer.phar dump-autoload -o",
                 "- Para instalar o composer: php composer.phar install",
                 "- Para atualizar o composer: php composer.phar self-update",
                 "- Servidor web embutido: php -S localhost:9000 -t /var/www/html/seuapp/public"
                 ]
}
```

Crie as pastas:

```
/SeuApp/public/
/SeuApp/src/
/SeuApp/src/Controller/
/SeuApp/test/
```

Dentro da pasta Controller, inclua o arquivo `ApplicationController.php`:

```
<?php

namespace SeuApp\Controller;

class ApplicationController
{
    public function controller()
    {
     return 'Olá Mundo';
    }
}
```

E na raiz de `/SeuApp/src`, o arquivo, `Application.php` com:

```
<?php

namespace SeuApp;

class Application extends Controller\ApplicationController
{

    public function index()
    {
       echo self::controller();
    }
}
```

Pronto, você já tem o básico de uma aplicação usando Autoload do composer.

Comment: Essa eu não conhecia, Ivan! +1

Comment: Opa, por essa eu não esperava, vou colocar em prática também. Valeu Ivan!

Comment: Ivan, acho que só tem um pequeno erro. Você não usa o `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` nesse caso, e sim o `PATH_SEPARATOR`. Porque assim o php criará uma lista de diretórios que podem ter os locais incluídos. A saída tem que ficar assim: "www/var;www/php;www/meu_projeto;". E isso depende do sistema operacional. Por isso tem que usar a constante

Comment: Mas independente de ser `DIRECTORY_PATH` ou `PATH_SEPARATOR`, eles não são considerados códigos portáveis?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, estou acostumado a fazer aplicações usando o autoload do composer, que também seria aplicável nesta situação.

Comment: Eu também prefixo usar o `composer`. Ele já faz tudo pra mim, é só dar o comando ;)

Answer (score 3):

Para auxiliar a resposta do `@rray`, reforço a idéia de você usar uma função de `glob` unida com `include/require`

```
function glob_include($glob, $flag = 0) {
    foreach (glob($glob, $flag) as $file) {
         require_once $file;
    }
}
```

O uso seria:

```
glob_include('diretorio/*.php');
```

Ainda outra opção é usar `GlobIterator`.

```
$it = new GlobIterator('diretorio/*.php');

foreach ($it as $file) {
    require $file->getRealpath();
}
```

Nesse caso, prefiro usar `getRealpath`, por conta do caminho ser passado ser absoluto. Já ouvi dizer que tem suas vantagens ;)

Comment: Opa essa chamada de função ficou boa :D, o que é o `$flag =0` ?

Comment: @rray, o Glob possui parâmetros como `GLOB_BRACE`.  Assim você pode fazer `glob('/dir/*.{txt,php,js,css}')`. Isso vai listar `txt,php,js e css` no mesmo glob ;)

Comment: Um filtro, entendi. Tbm não tinha notado q era a assinatura da função xD

Comment: Pena que não dá pra usar no `GlobIterator`. Ele é melhor, pois não salva tudo em um `array`.